# Converting all_shortest_paths vpaths to epaths in R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

Is there a simple way of converting or getting the epaths for the vpaths returned by all_shortest_paths?

```
library(igraph)

g <- make_ring(10)

# Returns epaths
shortest_paths(g, 1, 6, output="epath")

# Does not return epaths
all_shortest_paths(g, 1, 6)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `E()` function to turn a sequence of verticies into an edge list with the `path=` parameter.

```
lapply(all_shortest_paths(g, 1, 6)$res, function(x) E(g, path=x))
# [[1]]
# + 5/10 edges:
# [1] 1--10 9--10 8-- 9 7-- 8 6-- 7
# 
# [[2]]
# + 5/10 edges:
# [1] 1--2 2--3 3--4 4--5 5--6
```